# K-Means applied on a dataframe with too many features and zeros

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, k-means

I´m trying to cluster a dataframe with 36 features and a lot (88%) of zeros. It's my first job at ML, I started with K-Means, but for any K I choose, 99.5% of my data remains on cluster 0. I've tried some PCA do reduce features, but the same problem appeared.
Any thoughts on approaches I can try?

Comment: Your data is skewed. You need to give more weight to record with non zero values. You can give weight while doing fit transform. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried techniques such as sequential feature selection? These are so-called 'wrapper methods' where you add (for forward selection) or eliminate (for backward elimination) one feature at a time and assess the performance of the model accordingly. I tend to use supervised learning models in my job but I believe you can use sequential selection algorithms to assess unsupervised models as well. I have used the sklearn library for this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html